# All applications erased and software center does not open

Tags: 12.04, unity, software-center

I installed wine installed a few games and after a restart all the apps seems to be erased even system settings. The problem is the apps seems not visible only in unity and not elsewhere. Software center on the other side does not open at all.

Comment: Can you try running `software-center` in the terminal?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!